# Pandas mean vs sum/len

Tags: pandas, sum, mean

So this really baffled me. I was playing around with this [Kaggle dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/jsphyg/weather-dataset-rattle-package#) using pandas to learn statistics. I tried to calculate the mean of a column by using Series.sum()/len(Series), but then I remembered that Series.mean() exists. However, I accidentally discovered that pandas Series.mean() gives a slightly different result from Series.sum()/len(Series).

Steps to reproduce:
- Read the dataset using pd.read_csv()
- Take the column MaxTemp as the Series we will work on, named 'workdata' for example.
- Calculate workdata.mean() and workdata.sum()/len(workdata)

For now, I suspect that the difference is because decimals cannot be calculated 100% correctly by a computer and there are lots of decimals to work with here so the small differences could pile up.

If it is indeed the case, which one would give a more accurate result, and why?

Comment: `Series.mean()` excludes `nan` by default.

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks, it was silly of me to not realize this. The beginner datasets that I worked with did not have any nan value so I forgot that more realistic datasets are not so beautiful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of `Series.mean()` doesn't count the `NaN` values in the dataFrame. if you want to include `NaN` values you can use `Series.mean(skipna=False)`.

HAPPY_CODING...